# Yocto recipe to update /etc/fstab

Tags: yocto

I'm having trouble updating the `/etc/fstab` of my Linux distribution, when building it with Yocto.  I'm pretty new to Yocto, so maybe I'm off my rocker.

My latest attempt is to add a recipe named `base-files_%.bbappend`.

```
mount_smackfs () {
    cat >> ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/etc/fstab <<EOF

# Generated from smack-userspace
smackfs /smack smackfs smackfsdefault=* 0 0 

EOF
} 

ROOTFS_POSTPROCESS_COMMAND += "mount_smackfs; "
```

But, the output /etc/fstab on the distribution hasn't changed.  So the questions are:

1. Is there a better way to do this?
2. How can I tell if my .bbappend file was actually executed?

Comment: A useful thing- you can add a statement:
  bbplain "Am here now..."
inside a shell function within a recipe; it's echo'ed to stdout while 'cooking'. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59027178/779269

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`ROOTFS_POSTPROCESS_COMMAND` is handled in image recipes and **not in package recipes**. You have 2 possibilities.

- Update your fstab in `base-files_%.bbappend`:

  ```
  do_install_append () {
      cat >> ${D}${sysconfdir}/fstab <<EOF

  # Generated from smack-userspace
  smackfs /smack smackfs smackfsdefault=* 0 0 

  EOF
  }
  ```
- Update the fstab in your  image's recipe: In this case, you just append
  what you wrote above (in your post) in the image's recipe.

Comment: What do you do if the modifications depend on the .ext-image? Say you want to mount a partition by using a UUID?

Answer (score 9):

Create a new layer using

> yocto-layer create mylayer

inside it, create a folder called recipes-core and inside this folder 
create another folder called base-files.

Inside this folder create a file called *base-files_%.bbappend*, with the following content:

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS_append := "${THISDIR}/${PN}:"
```

Create another folder called base-files, inside which you should put a file called *fstab* with your configurations.

Make sure to enable your new layer in the *bblayers.conf* and it will work correctly, no need to create any append recipe or thing.
I had this issue and solved it using this method today.

Answer (score 5):

Given the following directory structure:

```
.
└── recipes-core/
    └── base-files/
        ├── base-files/
        │   └── fstab
        └── base-files_%.bbappend
```

and the following content for the recipe `base-files_%.bbappend` in question

```
DESCRIPTION = "Allows to customize the fstab"
PR = "r0"

FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/${PN}:"

SRC_URI += " \
   file://fstab \
"

do_install_append(){
   install -m 0644 ${WORKDIR}/fstab ${D}${sysconfdir}/
}
```

You can specify the fstab you want in that file and include this in your own custom layer. Once the compilation is finished you will have the custom fstab on the target system.

Comment: The file name need to be base-files_%.bbappend (with DASH).