# Ca't install my own syslog's syslog-startup.conf via Yocto

Tags: yocto

I was trying to create a new syslog-startup.conf by creating a busy-box%.bbappend having the following in it:

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/${PN}:"
SRC_URI += "\
    file://syslog-startup.conf \
"

do_install_append() {
    install -m 0644 ${WORKDIR}/syslog-startup.conf ${D}${sysconfdir}/syslog-startup.conf
}

FILE_${PN} += "\
    ${sysconfdir}/syslog-startup.conf \
"
```

My syslog-startup.conf is the same as the default one except i have it logging to a file instead of a buffer on system startup instead of my having to go in and change it manually. I never have this work. I always have the default .conf file installed on system startup. I should mention that I'm also having the same issue when i try to update another of my system files: /etc/fstab which also doesn't work and i end up with default file installed.

- Why am I not able to change/append to system files?
- Is there a better way to do this?
- Is there a way to find out if my .bbappend file got executed at all?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Yocto recipe to update /etc/fstab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43283825/yocto-recipe-to-update-etc-fstab)

Comment: @'Oleksandr Kravchuk'. I did see that topic and have tried out the answers but wasnt successful. Like i mentioned I have had this issue with syslog-startup.conf before. Regarding the profile pic I didnt realize that we are not allowed to use a face profile pic. I just took it off.

Comment: I just edited my question to explain my issue better.

Answer (score 1):

I had to alter the syslog-startup.conf for a different reason. How I managed to do it was by adding the below line in my busybox_%.bbappend

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/files:"
```

I added the modified syslog-startup.conf inside a folder called files. Where you place the file is upto you. Yocto will replace the default file with the file provided by the .bbapend file. So all you will have to do is point to the file in your busybox_%.bbapend file