# Yocto - Create and populate a separate /home partition

Tags: yocto, openembedded, yocto-wic

I'm creating quite a simple Yocto image based on x86.

I want the / file system to be readonly, so I set the

```
IMAGE_FEATURES_append = " read-only-rootfs "
```

in a custom copy of the original `core-image-minimal.bb`. I do want to have the `/home` writable and on a separate partition, though.

So, I'm adding a line

```
part /home --ondisk sda --fstype=ext4 --label home --align 1024 --size 600
```

in genericx86.wks. This creates the actual `/home` partition in the final wic image, but it naturally does not hold any data, as there's no corresponding `rootfs` for it. This leads to the following quite expected message after boot: `No directory, logging in with HOME=/`.

There's surprisingly little info about this on the internet. There's [this](https://lists.yoctoproject.org/pipermail/yocto/2016-March/029300.html) explanation:

> It's much more simpler to create or modify build
>   recipes to prepare one rootfs directory per partition.

I just wish there was any reference in the documentation or example on how to achieve that.

I can see that the partitions are being populated by python scripts (plugins) like `rootfs.py`, and that the image parameters like `IMAGE_ROOTFS_SIZE` are specified in mentioned image recipe files like the `genericx86.wks`, but this is just not enough for me to connect these pieces together.

I've read the [creating-partitioned-images-using-wic](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.6.2/dev-manual/dev-manual.html#creating-partitioned-images-using-wic) and the linked [openembedded kickstart](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.6.2/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#ref-kickstart) manuals, there are no clues there.

Appreciate someone's kind help.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

With WIC you can do something like this:

***`custom.wks.in`***:

```
...

part / --source rootfs --ondisk sda --fstype=ext4 --label system --exclude-path=home/    
part /home --source rootfs --rootfs-dir=${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/home --ondisk sda --fstype=ext4 --label home

...
```

Note it is important if you want to use `${IMAGE_ROOTFS}` in WKS file to name it with `.in` suffix.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick and correct reply. I've just tested it, works perfectly and also makes sense. 
I've copied the original `wks` file to my layer under wic folder: `wic/myfile.wks.in`, in my layer's `layer.conf` added `WKS_FILE="myfile.wks.in"`, and inside the file changed the partitions as per your recommendation. Also there's no problem to add `--size` setting to set the `/home`'s size.

Comment: It took so much time to understand how to do it the first time, glad it helped :)

Comment: One question here, is size of image(.wic) increased when we add any extra partition?
I have just created one partition of 1GB and my image size is increased by 1GB.

Comment: Wic adds 1Gb when package-management feature is enabled. To fix partition size, you have to set `IMAGE_ROOTFS_EXTRA_SPACE = "0"`, `IMAGE_OVERHEAD_FACTOR = "1.0"`, `IMAGE_ROOTFS_SIZE = "<size>"`, `IMAGE_ROOTFS_MAXSIZE = "<size>"`.

Comment: You can also add `--fixed-size=1024M` to wic lines (and also --align=<blocksize>).

Comment: If I want to do this with a new directory that is not there from the beginning, like "foo" instead of "home", will I have to do that in the recipe or in the image?

Comment: @alebo611 you can create a "foo" folder from recipe or ROOTFS_POSTPROCESS_COMMAND, it should work

Comment: Tried this - it creates the partition, but it's not mounted when the OS boots. What's the recommended way of mounting the partition created above? ROOTFS_POSTPROCESS_COMMAND or modifying the `.wks` file, or something else?

Comment: @Tomy normally, WIC automatically adds an entry for each line in `/etc/fstab`, is it the case for you? maybe you can check boot logs to see if there are any errors regarding disk mounting?

Comment: @Nayfe It is almost perfect but because of some reason, it doesn't preserve the permissions and the ownership of the files I put into the folder of the new partition. Any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: @TiborTakács I see that there is a patch for this  [wic: Fix permissions when using exclude or include path](https://patchwork.openembedded.org/patch/170778/), do your Yocto includes this ?

Comment: Hi @Nayfe. But what if the folder that I want to move to a separate partition contains files after rootfs build? How to clean that folder after partitioning? Because it takes space from rootfs partition.

Comment: @sopryshko it's what --exclude-path=home/ does, it removes "home" folder from rootfs partition. Or I didn't understand your question :(

Comment: @Nayfe thank you for the quick reply. Oh, I missed that part of your answer. Now everything works well

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue, and the solution proposed by Nayfe did work (a bit) for me: it created the partition and filled it with the content of `/home`. But the partition was not mounted, and the file permissions in `/home` were broken.

To mount the partition, I added an entry in `/etc/fstab` (helped with: [Yocto recipe to update /etc/fstab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43283825/yocto-recipe-to-update-etc-fstab))

To fix the ownership/permission issue, I used `--change-directory=home` instead of `--rootfs-dir=${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/home`. (It also fixes the warning emitted during `do_image_wic` which was helpful in searching for the source of the issue: `.../pseudo folder does not exist. Usernames and permissions will be invalid`)