# Yocto - Warrior - how to create wic image installer

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, openembedded, yocto-wic

Hi: I'm on Yocto warrior 2.7.1.

I am a bit stuck on one thing. I needed to create an additional r/w partition for persistent application storage, so I found that the only way to accomplish this was with `wic`.

Thanks to this answer I was able to get an image with a R/W partition working via my USB flash drive:

[Yocto - Create and populate a separate /home partition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56187209/yocto-create-and-populate-a-separate-home-partition)

Added the partition to:

`meta-intel/wic/systemd-bootdisk-microcode.wks.in`

And all went well.

The only problem is that I don't see a way to create a usb installer image.  I see that in more recent versions of poky (zeus and dunfell) that meta-intel/wic also has image-installer.wks.in which creates an installer image suitable for running from USB.

Unfortunately I'm stuck on warrior so was hoping somebody might have some ideas apart from moving forward to zeus or dunfell.