# Create second file system/partition in Yocto

Tags: yocto

I have a Yocto recipe to create the rootfs. I want to create another ext4 file system that includes only a few files, and merge it into the original image as a separate partition with a special mount point. `wks` file support this: `part /myfiles --source rawcopy ...` that copies files from an existing image, however, I do not know how I could generate this ext4 image in the same Yocto build step.

The [Yocto - Create and populate a separate /home partition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56187209/yocto-create-and-populate-a-separate-home-partition) almost works, however, I want to change file permissions that does not work with this solution.

How is it possible to tackle this?

Comment: Which issues are you encountering with the file permissions? If you read some new comments into the link you've posted, @nayfe answered about a patch (currently unavailable), which version are you using?